# Which off-the-shelf wireless door/window sensor can I easily interface with Home Assistant?

Tags: wireless, home-security, home-assistant, door-sensor

I am thinking of setting up my own home security system using Home Assistant. For motion sensors I'm going to build Wi-Fi MQTT transmitters using the WeMos board.

But for door sensors I want something battery-powered, with a small form factor that is OK to look at. Which off-the-shelf wireless door sensor can I easily interface with Home Assistant?

Comment: I am asking for advice for choosing a wireless battery powered door-sensor that will interface with Home Assistant. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: Yeah; it was a bit ambiguous. I've updated it, hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I am running Home Assistant on a Raspberry Pi and have had a lot of success using the Aeotec Gen5 Z-Wave control stick (USB). I bought several of the GoControl WNK01-21KIT kits and the door sensors have been working really well, but that is just one of many Z-Wave door sensor options.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old question, but since the landscape has changed in these years, I thought of adding another answer if helpful to anyone else.

1. There is a good Aqara contact sensors are quite good, especially the new ones are smaller and matter compatible, if that is important. This is Zigbee device.
2. If you need a Wifi device, Shelly contact sensors are quite good as well, with a long lasting battery life and quite a low presence on the door / window. Hope that is helpful.

Comment: I use several of the Aqara sensors and like them.